# Is there a 'man' for python?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a CLI like 'man.py' dedicated to Python?

ex,

```
man.py os.system
> system(command) -> exit_status
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is using `pydoc function` on the shell, with `function` being either the name of a builtin or the qualified name (`module.function`) of a function in a module:

```
> PAGER=cat pydoc urllib.urlencode
[adrian@hades:~]> PAGER=cat pydoc urllib.urlencode
Help on function urlencode in urllib:

urllib.urlencode = urlencode(query, doseq=0)
    Encode a sequence of two-element tuples or dictionary into a URL query string.
...
```

(`PAGER=cat` was only used to make it copy&pastable here)

When using IPython you can use `function?` to view the docstring of `function` or `function??` for a more verbose view that includes the full sourcecode for functions written in python.

In the normal python shell you can use `help(function)` for this. However, in my opinion the IPython way is more comfortable.

Comment: or `?function` which is equal to `function?`

Answer (score 22):

The pydoc module provides it:

```
$ python -m pydoc os.system
Help on built-in function system in os:

os.system = system(...)
    system(command) -> exit_status

    Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
$
```